# How to calculate double factorial (multiply odds) with recursion?[homework]

Tags: recursion, factorial

How should I alter the factorial recursion, to calculate only the odd or only the double elements of the factorial?For example if:

```
 multiplyOdds(4)
```

the result should return 1*3*5*7 =105

I know how recursion works, I just need a bit of help which approach I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `multiplyOdds(n)` needs to multiply the first `n` odd numbers? Given that the nth odd number is equal to `2 * n - 1`, you can easily write a recursive solution like the one below in Haskell:

```
multiplyOdds :: Int -> Int
multiplyOdds n = multiplyOddsTail n 1

multiplyOddsTail :: Int -> Int -> Int
multiplyOddsTail n acc = case n of
  1 -> acc
  n -> multiplyOddsTail (n - 1) (acc * (n * 2 - 1))
```